# Android login and register MySQL HTTPS website

Tags: php, android, mysql, https

i already have created a website which is currently hosting on Hostinger. My website link starts with https:// myweb.com instead of http. I have tried a lot of codes but i cant login through my app. Actually, i want to connect my android app with my online website database(MySQL). But i could not find any solution. I also tried `HttpURLConnection` syntax but it is not working because my website's protocol is `https://` . Here is my code in which i want to register user through my android app (i am using GET method in PHP script):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText name,email,pass;
    private Button login,register;
    private static final String REGISTER_URL="https://bomvibe.com/Android/signup.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        register=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });

    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String uname=name.getText().toString();
        String uemail=email.getText().toString();
        String upass=pass.getText().toString();
        register(uname,uemail,upass);
    }

    private void register(String uname, String uemail, String upass) {
        String urlsuffix="?username="+uname+"&email="+uemail+"&password="+upass;
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog dialogue;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
                dialogue=ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
             //   dialogue.setTitle("Please Wait");
             //   dialogue.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s){
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                dialogue.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String s=params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
                try{
                    URL url=new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                    HttpURLConnection cn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cn.getInputStream()));
                    String result;
                    result=bufferedReader.readLine();
                    return result;

                }catch (Exception e){
                  return null;
                }
            }
        }
        RegisterUser regUser=new RegisterUser();
        regUser.execute(urlsuffix);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect android app to your MySql Database you need to write web services.

A web service is a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network. In other word in web service we write all the database query and handle all types of HTTP request and response with data in JSON formate. Web services is written in many language such as JAVA,PHP,Python,.net ect. This web services are execute on server side. To get access to this web service you need run your server(Apache server) and get the URL of web service file running on server.

Now while calling this web service from android side I will suggest you to use volley lib. This will help you make HTTP request and easier for understanding.

Volley lib integration:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

For server side

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-eclipse-javase1/ws-eclipse-javase1.html

Comment: can you please explain how to do it. I know PHP and JAVA. but i do not know about web service. Please guide me a little. Thanks for reply sir.

Comment: Sir Can I please inbox you privately??